# How to print array elements in table horizontally and after some element vertically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have array with numbers. if I am printing array in table in rows it prints all elements horizontally but I want to print array like 3 elements horizontally and then again at next line 3 elements horizontally, my Jquery is:

```
$.get("",{id:$(this).val()}, function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    drawRow(data[i]);
  }
  function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<th />")
    row.empty();
    $("#delDish").append(row);
    row.append($("<button class='btn btn-lg btn-success' value='"+ rowData.item_id +"'>" + rowData.item_name + "</button>"));                
  } });
```

what i need is aaray should be print like:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how to do it using Jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wayotejatu/edit?html,js,output

First, populating the `data` array with some dummy data:

```
var data = [
    { item_id: 1, item_name: 'a' },
    { item_id: 2, item_name: 'b' },
    { item_id: 3, item_name: 'c' },
    { item_id: 4, item_name: 'd' },
    { item_id: 5, item_name: 'e' },
    { item_id: 6, item_name: 'f' },
    { item_id: 7, item_name: 'g' }
];
```

Then, looping through the data, create a new row only if the row index is a multiplication of three:

```
if (i % 3 === 0) {
    row = $('<tr />');
    $("#delDish tbody").append(row);
}
```

Then, in the `drawRow` function, always appending to the last row `$("#delDish tbody tr:last-child")`

Please notice the HTML structure is a bit different than the original one in the question:

```
<table id="delDish">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```